# How to get last call in Android Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi

How I can get last call (it't doesnt matter lost or recieved) in Android Delphi XE7?

I know about

`CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall..`

... in Java. But what about Delphi ?

Comment: Delphi has access to Android's Java APIs via its JNI Bridge.  If Delphi does not already provide a Pascal translation for the CallLog API, you can use the Java2OP tool to generate a translation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in delphi JCallLog_CallsClass like this :

```
TJCallLog_Calls.JavaClass.getLastOutgoingCall(...);
```